# Compile each XAML page as DLL

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I understand my "this" query may sound very generic but any pointers to guide is highly appreciated.

We are building an WPF application based on MVVM design pattern (with DevXpress controls) and want to achieve the following.

1. There will be one .EXE file which will run the applications.
2. All my XAML files need to be as DLL [Why? - Reasons specified below].
3. Call the DLL dynamically and load with in the WPF application.

[Why?? - Reasons]
Our application is a client/server intranet application. We are planning to use ClickOnce deployment to deploy the application. In case there are any changes to the application, my though is we don't have to change the entire application and recompile it and then deploy so the client machines will be updated.

Instead we can change only those screen or XAML file which are needed and update on the server and ClickOnce will automatically handles the updates on the clients. This also, helps us in maintaining our application and less troublesome for the developers and UI designers.

I am welcome to another better approach also.

Comment: why not create a single dll which will hold your styles controls and update it when needed?

Comment: you should have a look at MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) it is a great way to do what you want and is very extensible http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MEFlook&referringTitle=Samples

Comment: @makc, actually it not style or controls, its a complete UI which has all the events and DB bind properties etc.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 thank you let me go through MEF.